# CollapsingToolbarLayout in Fragment title not set when collapsed

Tags: android, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport

I have a toolbar in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`. I set title in `onResume`(). When I open activity and fragment, the title is shown correctly. But if I collapse it and press home button and open it again, it is not there anymore. However if I press home button when layout is expanded, the title appears as expected. Here is the code of setting the title:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("TITLE HERE");
        toolbar.setTitle("TITLE HERE");
    }
```

What is wrong? Is it a bug in support library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's a bug some version of the library: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183333 just update to the latest and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the title of the collapsing toolbar layout. Example:

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("title");
```

Comment: why are you adding it in onresume and not in oncreate?